# Suppose $\sum a_n x^n$ be a power series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Suppose  $\sum a_n x^n $ be a power series. Prove that if $0<\lim\sup|a_n|<\infty$, then the power series has radius of convergence $R=1$.

I really have no idea where I have to start can anyone help me with the problem please?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You can give a more informative title.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. All you can deduce is that $R\ge1$. This is straightforward: the condition implies that $\sum_n a_nx^n$ converges for $|x|\le1$, by comparison.

REPLY TO EDITED QUESTION

This is textbook stuff. The sum converges for $|x|<1$ by comparison with the geometric series, so $R\ge1$. But it diverges for $x=1$ as $|a_n|
\not\to0$, so $R\le1$.

Comment: ...sorry i edited question now

Comment: ...i am really sorry i had mistake with writing question can please answer me now thank you

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown ..but question says radis of converence =1